# How to resolve the prestashop notice?

Tags: php, html, css, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to resolve these notices that keep displaying in my logs:

```
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /srv/myShop/shop/cache/smarty/compile/4c/b2/41/4cb2418065875a76c823a0076b8a95132c849e33.file.product-list-colors.tpl.cache.php on line 32
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: colors_list in /srv/myShop/shop/cache/smarty/compile/4c/b2/41/4cb2418065875a76c823a0076b8a95132c849e33.file.product-list-colors.tpl.cache.php on line 32
```

Here is a snippet from product-list-colors.tpl.cache.php including line 32 (3rd line):

```
<ul class="color_to_pick_list clearfix">
    <?php  $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['color'] = new Smarty_Variable; $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['color']->_loop = false;
 $_from = $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['colors_list']->value; if (!is_array($_from) && !is_object($_from)) { settype($_from, 'array');}
foreach ($_from as $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['color']->key => $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['color']->value) {
$_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['color']->_loop = true;
```

And here you got themes/simple-great/product-list-colors.tpl:

```
<ul class="color_to_pick_list clearfix">
{foreach from=$colors_list item='color'}
    <li>
        <a
        href="{$link->getProductLink($color.id_product, null, null, null, null, null, $color.id_product_attribute)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"
        id="color_{$color.id_product_attribute|intval}"
        class="color_pick"
        style="background: {$color.color};">
        </a>
    </li>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: I might have found a solution for these notices - I found a file product-list-colors.tpl for previous Prestashop version 1.6.1.0 which is SLIGHTLY different from that of mine - here is a link http://thecodedirectory.com/prestashop/1.6.1.0/prestashop/themes/default-bootstrap/product-list-colors.tpl

I just need you confirmation that it is OK.

Comment: As you see it's basically the same but with additional checks if vars exist so they don't throw notices. I don't know if you bought your theme or wrote your own, but that's what happens when people make themes and don't follow the code flow of original theme. I've had the "pleasure" of working with a theme like that in my last project - took me a month to fix everything and sadly themes like that pass quality checks on themeforest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open /themes/YOUR_THEME/product-list-colors.tpl

Search for

```
{foreach from=$colors_list item='color'}
```

and add a condition that will check if the '$colors_list' variable is set or not. The final code will be something like as follows:

```
{if isset($colors_list)}
    //Current foreach loop code
{/if}
```